# Mysterious ORA-00933 When I create two parallel requests;

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework, task-parallel-library, odp.net

My problem is similar with https://community.oracle.com/thread/3728543?start=0&tstart=0.

I create two parallel requests. One of requests contains query with FirstOrDefault.  I do requests in infinity loop.  On the 5th and 6th I received exception : ORA-00933;

In the end of query I discovered:

**ORDER BY "Project1"."CREATION_DATE" DESC
WHERE (ROWNUM <= (1) )**

Technologies:Entity Framework + Odp.net.

This bug is appeared 
accidentally.Every 10 requests.

Thank you! Best regards.

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` `Action: Correct the syntax by removing the inappropriate clauses. It may be possible to duplicate the removed clause with another SQL statement. For example, to order the rows of a view, do so when querying the view and not when creating it. This error can also occur in SQL*Forms applications if a continuation line is indented. Check for indented lines and delete these spaces.`

Comment: `ORDER BY "Project1"."CREATION_DATE" DESC WHERE (ROWNUM <= (1) )` the syntax is wrong... so problem is somewhere in your code and database correctly raises the exception

Comment: You are right but 8/10 queries  correctly but only 2/10 bad. I think that is odp.net bug with parallel queries.(All queries completely identity)

Comment: All queries were generated by Entity Framework

Comment: please paste your .net code

Comment: @VadimKuptsov we've got the same issue on a project here, let me know if you managed to find what was wrong.

Comment: The problem was in FirstOrDefault(). In parallel environment 
ROWNUM <= (1) link to another query sometimes. We have started to use DevArt Oracle provider and don't have problems with parallel queries.